# Mount point fails to reinstate after reboot of Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, mount, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm

I have created a virtual machine with mount point of directory stored locally. It is mounted on /dev/sdb as shown below.

```
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─sda1                             8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                             8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                             8:5    0 99.5G  0 part 
   ├─r730bld--04--vm22--vg-root   252:0    0 95.5G  0 lvm  /
   └─r730bld--04--vm22--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                                8:16   0  200G  0 disk /var/details
sdc                                8:32   0  200G  0 disk
```

I have also added the details for the same in /etc/fstab.

```
/dev/sdb /var/details xfs rw,user,auto,_netdev 0 0
```

But after i do the reboot of this virtual machine, mount points are lost and i get below output in lsblk.

```
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                8:0    0  100G  0 disk  
├─sda1                             8:1    0  487M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                             8:2    0    1K  0 part  
└─sda5                             8:5    0 99.5G  0 part  
  ├─r730bld--04--vm22--vg-root   252:0    0 95.5G  0 lvm   /
  └─r730bld--04--vm22--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                                8:16   0  200G  0 disk  
└─QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00002          252:2    0  200G  0 mpath 
sdc                                8:32   0  200G  0 disk  
└─QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00003          252:3    0  200G  0 mpath
```

This VM is created on a KVM box. I am not sure if this is a generic bug or problem in my setup.

Comment: What happens when you run mount -a after the reboot? Do all the entries in /etc/fstab mount?

Comment: it says 
root:~# mount -a 
mount: /dev/sdb is already mounted or /var/details busy

Comment: Check the output of dmesg to see if anything is reported.

Comment: i got only this error in whole output of dmesg. [    6.616492] device-mapper: table: 252:2: multipath: error getting device. And there was no reference of /var/details or /dev/sdb

Comment: Why are you using _netdev when the device isn't a network device and therefore doesn't need to wait for the network device to come up?

Comment: attached disk are SAN devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by modifying /etc/fstab using UUID of the disk instead of the name.

```
UUID="1a1cbf5d-b358-48fe-adf4-aa748b55e6c4" var/details xfs rw,user,auto,_netdev 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Grrr.... yes, there two possible issues to content with, the first being systemd on recent machines, and there I'm sorry to say I have no intention to wonder about that one this week, however, let's look at the second issue:

The recent advice is to make use of the most appropriate /dev/disk/{by-id|by-label|by-partlabel|by-partuuid|by-uuid}, as the order of the devices (especially with friend(?) systemd) might change around. Okay, I have a historical preference to the Solaris and old devfsd naming conventions, but the disk/by- does work.

Adding to that, I'd also advice you to reconsider using a partition, just to have it better recognized than the raw disk as a filesystem. Perhaps even (during the mkfs or a tunefs afterwards) label the partition, that way systemd might behave also a tad better.